# Struts 2 xml validation, form resubmission

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2, xml-validation

My question is relation to struts 2 form validation, done via XML.

I have an action that is validated and is validating properly, where a user submits information to a list and the list is updated.

If the field is length 0, validation errors are given.

My problem is if validation fails, the user cannot resubmit the form. It will not allow any submissions beyond

**TrustedAction.java**

```
    public String saveOrUpdate()
    {   

        trustedBo.saveOrUpdateTrusted(trusted);

        //reload the trusted list

            listTrusted = null;
        listTrusted = trustedBo.listTrusted();
        return SUCCESS;

    }
```

**struts.xml**

```
        <action name="saveOrUpdateTrusted" class="trustedActionBean"         
    method="saveOrUpdate">
            <result name="input">/WEB-INF/views/TrustedList.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/views/TrustedList.jsp</result>
        </action>
@SkipValidation
public String execute() {
listTrusted = trustedBo.listTrusted();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**TrustedAction-validator.xml**

```
     <field name="src_ip">
     <field-validator type="requiredstring">
         <message key="source ip required"/>
     </field-validator>
      </field>`
```

**trustedlist.jsp**

```
<s:form action="saveOrUpdateTrusted" method="post" cssClass="form-horizontal" theme="simple" validate="true">
    <s:push value="trusted">
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Row&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th align="left">SRC IP&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th align="left">Protocol&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th align="left">From Pattern&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th align="left">TAG&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
```

I have tried using `Preparable`, but this isn't what I need.

I need the field errors displayed under the text bar on the form like a fielderror, which is what I have now.

Comment: field errors are displayed dynamically or you might use a tag.

Comment: Hey, I realize now I posted the wrong code from the form. Here is the field for updating:

<td align="left" width="5%">
   <span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
    <s:textfield name="src_ip"></s:textfield>
    <s:fielderror fieldName="src_ip" />
   </span>
  </td>

Comment: Try to remove <span> also if you use fielderror the corresponding theme should be applied.

Comment: I have removed the span and nothing has changed. The field errors are being displayed properly, but my problem is once validation is called no further form submissions are taken, edit doesn't work, delete doesn't work and submit.

Comment: The validation errors prevents the action from execution, hence no form submission is made. You might try to remove the workflow interceptor from the stack to see how it's working or add an annotation, or override the action config. Do something.

Comment: The form will still be submitted; server-side validation doesn't prevent the client from sending the form. It's unclear what the actual issue is you're having.

Comment: If validation returns success, the form executes successfully and updates the list properly. If validation fails, no further form submissions are taken it seems. I don't know enough about how "post" works on forms, but it seems like this return of input from validation never changes after it has been returned once from the validation. There is no chance of a resubmit upon validation failing. I think the problem is this "input" return is stuck in the form's POST, and doesn't get changed upon resubmission.

Comment: I should also add that this is all done within one dynamic page, the form for updating and the list.

Comment: Don't use `<s:push>`, remove `validate="true"` from form.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I have tried everything here and it is still not working. I should add that it is validating correctly also upon resubmission (fielderror duplicates if the field is empty, it doesn't if I submit a random string) but something is happening that is blocking the POST from saving to the list.

Comment: I solved it, I would share but I figured out you can use the struts interceptor stack when extending hibernate-default, so I went back to the annotated POJO structure and worked from that. 

Thanks for all your help!